# Filter duplicate entries when exporting items with append mode in csvexports in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, export-to-csv, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to figure out how to pre-check whether an item is already present in a row in the csv file to be exported. If the item is not present, then the item needs to be appended. Else the item should be discarded. So far I have done following in item pipeline but it doesn't work, as it appends to the csv file no matter what.

My Pipelines.py:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
import csv

class BlogscrapePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):

        file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'a+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['Title','Link','Comments','Words']
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        with open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'rt',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            reader=csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                if item not in row:
                    self.exporter.export_item(item)
                    return item
```

The items.py:

```
import scrapy

class BlogscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):

    Title=scrapy.Field()
    Link=scrapy.Field()
    Comments=scrapy.Field()
    Words=scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a item pipeline is the best way to filter duplicate items

```
 from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

 class FilterDuplicateItemsPipeline(object):

     items = set()
     configured = False

     def process_item(self, item, spider):
         if not self.configured:
            # TODO:
            # Extract items from previous csv
            # Add each item to the self.items
            self.configured = True

         if item not in self.items:
             self.items.add(item)
             return item
         else:
             raise DropItem('Duplicate item %s' % item)
```

You will have to add it also to your list of items pipelines on your `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    '{your_path}.FilterDuplicateItemsPipeline': 500,
}
```

Edit: This is not a good solution. Please read the comments below.

Comment: so do i need to create a separate class with your code in pipeline.py above or I have to adjust these in my code??

Comment: Yes, you have to create this class in the `pipeline.py` file, and you wont need your custom CsvItemExporter

Comment: so I created a separate class in pipelines.py and added it to settings.py. Now I am getting NameError:name 'items' is not defined for this line.if item not in items: Any help with that??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test the code and forgot to add `self.` when accessing `items`. It should be fixed now.

Comment: The error is gone but the csv file is appended with same rows that pre exists in csv. Its not filtering out.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question properly. I think you were talking about duplicates items from the same execution. To exclude the items already present on the previous CSV you will have to add an initial step of filling the `self.items` var with the values in the CSV.

Comment: I did another fix to adjust it to your requeriments. But in this case It's better to move the logic of my current `process_item` into the `process_item` of your custom CSV Exporter

Comment: if i move the process item logic to my custom csvexporter i get AttributeError: 'BlogscrapePipeline' object has no attribute 'configured'       def process_item(self, item, spider):
  
  if not self.configured:
   self.configured = True
  if item not in self.items:
   with open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'rt',encoding='utf-8') as file:

    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
     if item not in row:
      self.exporter.export_item(item)
      self.items.add(item)
      return item
     else:
      raise DropItem('Duplicate item %s' % item)
please guide me

Comment: You can't just copy paste this code into yours, but the idea it's pretty similar. Read the previous items on the CSV, keep a set with the list of items already on the csv and check that new items are not on the set before adding to the csv

Answer (score 0):

Your test seems uncorrect, because for example if it sees that the item isn't in the first row, even if it is in the second row, it export it. You must export only after checking all rows. Consider also [save elements in a set before exporting and check the news against the set](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter), more efficient I think in respect to file.

Comment: Yup I think that's where the problem is. Thanks for the enlightment. However can you expain how am I supposed to check all the rows. Also about the duplicate filter option you provided I am not getting how to implement it. Should I implement it as separate class then how I should reference it to my Pipeline process item to fllter out duplicate?

Comment: You can add the lines in the example in your pipeline, then use one or more unique fields of your item for saving in the set and checking if present. Take a look how a Python set works.

Comment: I edited the code according to example like this but it didn't do any magic.`                def process_item(self, item, spider):
  
  
  if item['Title'] in self.ids_seen:
   raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
  else:
   self.ids_seen.add(item['Title'])
   self.exporter.export_item(item)
   return item